# Why does µ shows like M in django's admin?

Tags: django, unicode, character-encoding, django-admin

I'm using the following code in a django model to format a column in the admin interface:

```
def formatted_mu(self):
    return "%.1f%%" % self.mu
formatted_mu.short_description = u'\u03BC'
```

For some reason instead of showing µ in the heading, it shows M. I know this should work as when I tried u'\u03A3' I did receive ∑.

Encoding reference:

- [Encoding for ∑](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3a3/index.htm)
- [Encoding for µ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03bc/index.htm)

**UPDATE:**
I've discovered that other lower case Greek letters are switched with their capital counterparts too. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: You were so close to answering your own question: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/039c/index.htm

Comment: @MusiGenesis - u'\u039C' also gives M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid capitalizing a model name by setting a `verbose_model_plural` in the Meta class of your model definition in models.py with the setting as you want and a space as the first character.

E.g.,

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
     class Meta:
         verbose_name_plural = u' \u03BC'
```

EDIT1: My initial solution didn't work, as django always capitalizes the first letter even in a verbose_name_plural (though it won't automatically convert the other letters to lowercase like the admin normally does to model names.)  However, making the first letter of the verbose name be a space, it works.  Note since the name is in a html table (which ignores whitespace before the first/last character) the space in the verbose model name doesn't get noticed to the user.

EDIT2: Or to avoid capitalizing a field name (sorry -- didn't read question carefully).

```
class AnAverageModel(models.Model):
     mean = models.FloatField(u" \u03BC")
```

Comment: That's great, but it changes the model name, but a certain field's name, which is what I'm looking for

Comment: @Jonathan: could you just change `short_description` to `u' \u03BC'` ?

Comment: @jumbob - your comment above and your EDIT2 worked marvelously, thanks

Answer (score 3):

That M is a capital Mu.  Sigma looks distinctive, but capital-Mu looks like our M.

Answer (score 2):

Django capitalizes the first letter of any field